# Use table fields as stored procedure parameters (to redistribute a given table fields into other tables)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the structure of the following tables:

```
ITEMS:
╔═══════════╤══════════════╤══════╤═════╤═════════╤════════════════╗
║ FIELD     │ TYPE         │ NULL │ KEY │ DEFAULT │ EXTRA          ║
╠═══════════╪══════════════╪══════╪═════╪═════════╪════════════════╣
║ id        │ int          │ NO   │ PRI │         │ auto_increment ║
╟───────────┼──────────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼────────────────╢
║ image_url │ varchar(255) │ NO   │     │         │                ║
╚═══════════╧══════════════╧══════╧═════╧═════════╧════════════════╝

ITEM_TRANSLATIONS:
╔═════════════╤══════════════╤══════╤═════╤═════════╤════════════════╗
║ FIELD       │ TYPE         │ NULL │ KEY │ DEFAULT │ EXTRA          ║
╠═════════════╪══════════════╪══════╪═════╪═════════╪════════════════╣
║ id          │ int          │ NO   │ PRI │         │ auto_increment ║
╟─────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼────────────────╢
║ description │ varchar(255) │ NO   │     │         │                ║
╟─────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼────────────────╢
║ title       │ varchar(45)  │ NO   │     │         │                ║
╚═════════════╧══════════════╧══════╧═════╧═════════╧════════════════╝
```

I also have a stored procedure that redistributes its parameters to the needed tables this way:

```
DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addItem //
    CREATE PROCEDURE addItem (
        IN _item__image_url VARCHAR(255),
        IN _item_translations__title VARCHAR(45),
        IN _item_translations__description VARCHAR(255)
    )

    BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO item (
                image_url
            )
            VALUES (
                _item__image_url
            );


            INSERT INTO item_translations (
                item_id,
                title,
                `description`
            )
            VALUES (
                LAST_INSERT_ID(),
                _item_translations__title,
                _item_translations__description
            );
        COMMIT ;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

If I call this procedure this way:

```
CALL addBrand(
    "/images/items.png",
    "My Item",
    "An oversimplified item just for this question."
);
```

I got the following as expected:

```
ITEMS:
╔════╤═══════════════════╗
║ ID │ IMAGE_URL         ║
╠════╪═══════════════════╣
║ 19 │ /images/items.png ║
╚════╧═══════════════════╝

ITEM_TRANSLATIONS:
╔════╤═════════╤═════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID │ ITEM_ID │ TITLE   │ DESCRIPTION                                    ║
╠════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 7  │ 19      │ My Item │ An oversimplified item just for this question. ║
╚════╧═════════╧═════════╧════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have a third table with *N* rows with all the required fields:

```
IMPORTED_TABLE
╔════╤══════════════╤══════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════╗
║ ID │ TITLE        │ DESCRIPTION                      │ IMAGE_URL              ║
╠════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╣
║ 42 │ Another Item │ Yet another oversimplified item. │ /images/items_2.png    ║
╟────┼──────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 43 │ This Item    │ A nice item                      │ /images/thanks.png     ║
╟────┼──────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 44 │ Trixie Item  │ The great and powerful item!     │ /images/mlp/trixie.png ║
╚════╧══════════════╧══════════════════════════════════╧════════════════════════╝
```

**How can I use this table contents as parameters of the stored procedure to be able to populate the required tables as needed?**
In order to get this:

```
ITEMS:
╔════╤════════════════════════╗
║ ID │ IMAGE_URL              ║
╠════╪════════════════════════╣
║ 19 │ /images/items.png      ║
╟────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 20 │ /images/items_2.png    ║
╟────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 21 │ /images/thanks.png     ║
╟────┼────────────────────────╢
║ 22 │ /images/mlp/trixie.png ║
╚════╧════════════════════════╝

ITEM_TRANSLATIONS
╔════╤═════════╤══════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID │ ITEM_ID │ TITLE        │ DESCRIPTION                                    ║
╠════╪═════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 7  │ 19      │ My Item      │ An oversimplified item just for this question. ║
╟────┼─────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 8  │ 20      │ Another Item │ Yet another oversimplified item.               ║
╟────┼─────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 9  │ 21      │ This Item    │ A nice item                                    ║
╟────┼─────────┼──────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 10 │ 22      │ Trixie Item  │ The great and powerful item!                   ║
╚════╧═════════╧══════════════╧════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Obviously this is an oversimplified example. In the stored procedure there are different data treatments to all the parameters, so I don't have to recreate the stored procedure.

Comment: use another stored procedure with a cursor that loops over both joined tables and call the insert procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the `ID` values in your `IMPORTED_TABLE` supposed to be used for the `ID` in `ITEMS`?

If so, then you can do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO ITEMS (ID, IMAGE_URL) 
 SELECT ID, IMAGE_URL FROM IMPORTED_TABLE;

INSERT INTO ITEM_TRANSLATIONS (ITEM_ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION)
 SELECT ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION FROM IMPORTED_TABLE;

COMMIT;
```

This will use the `ID` values verbatim for both `ITEMS.ID` and `ITEM_TRANSLATIONS.ITEM_ID`.

However, if you want to insert the URLs and ignore the `ID` values in the imported data, and let the `ITEMS` table generate new ID values, then you can do it in a batch and assume the batch is a set of consecutive values.

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO ITEMS (IMAGE_URL) 
 SELECT IMAGE_URL FROM IMPORTED_TABLE;

SET @START_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID() - 1;

INSERT INTO ITEM_TRANSLATIONS (ITEM_ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION)
 SELECT (@START_ID := @START_ID+1), TITLE, DESCRIPTION FROM IMPORTED_TABLE;

COMMIT;
```

Is it safe to assume the values are consecutive? By default, yes it is safe. For example, MySQL's JDBC driver makes this assumption when you do batched inserts, so it can return the set of generated ID values.

The exception is if you are on a MySQL instance that has the option `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2` set, the values are not guaranteed to be consecutive. This is not the default, so it probably won't apply in your case.

(read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html for details)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. `imported_table.id` is just an incremental number not related to anything else. So I tried your second block of code. I managed to get things done this way BUT the only problem is the `auto_increment` value in each table (`items` and `items_translations`) is unexpectedly increased the number of rows inserted this way...

So if I inserted 16 rows this way, the `auto_increment` value for `id` is now 32. So I get ID like _... 14, 15, 16, 32, 33, 34..._instead of _... 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19..._ Can you please be kind enough to help me understand this? THANKS

Comment: I have a vague recollection that this is a known bug, but I did not find a reference with a few minutes of searching. Make sure you are using the most current version of MySQL.

Comment: I'm using [latest MySQL version to date: 8.0.21](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/) so maybe this bug is still present. Anyway, I fix the issue myself: I've shared how in my question. Thanks for all your kind help!

Comment: The solution you show doesn't work if you have more than one concurrent session inserting data into the table. But if you are in control and can guarantee only one client at a time, it might be a sufficient solution for your needs.

Comment: It's good to know, thank you. For now, it's OK as I'm the only one who will use this so there won't be a problem. I wonder how to avoid the caveat you mention...

Comment: The only way to avoid it with your design is to use [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) before you start, so no other session can insert its own rows, and cause the auto-increment to advance.

Comment: Another solution is to insert `items` rows one at a time, and collect the LAST_INSERT_ID() from each one so you can reference it in `item_translations`. That way it doesn't matter if other sessions are taking some of the id's from the auto-increment sequence.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted an answer improvement on behalf of the question author, in order to move it to the answer space)*.

Thanks to the accepted answer, I was able to solve this challenge. However the `auto_increment` value is increased the number of rows inserted/read (possible because a bug in MySQL as stated in a comment).

So I needed to create another stored procedure to be able to get the max ID value and use it to alter all the involved tables. This stored procedure is the following:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tableMaxID //
CREATE PROCEDURE tableMaxID(IN nameOfTable VARCHAR(20))
    BEGIN
        SET @qry=CONCAT('SELECT MAX(id) INTO @maxIdValue FROM ', nameOfTable);
        PREPARE st FROM @qry;
        EXECUTE st;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
        
        SET @maxIdValue := @maxIdValue + 1;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, I added this fix to the original stored procedure for each involved table:

```
DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addItem //
    CREATE PROCEDURE addItem ()

    BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;
            /* INSERT INTO the corresponding tables */
            INSERT INTO items (image_url) 
                SELECT CONCAT(`items.image_url`, ' testing') FROM imported_table;
            
            SET @START_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID() - 1;
            
            INSERT INTO items_translations (item_id, title, `description`)
                SELECT (@START_ID := @START_ID+1), `items_translations.title`, `brands_translations.description` FROM imported_table;
            
            /***********/
            /* Fix brands auto_increment */
            CALL tableMaxID('items');                
            SET @qry=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE items AUTO_INCREMENT =', @maxIdValue);
            PREPARE st FROM @qry;
            EXECUTE st;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
            
            /* Fix items_translations auto_increment */
            CALL tableMaxID('items_translations');                
            SET @qry=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE items_translations AUTO_INCREMENT =', @maxIdValue);
            PREPARE st FROM @qry;
            EXECUTE st;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
        COMMIT;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, all that's needed is to call the stored procedure and the given data will be inserted into the corresponding tables, fixing the involved tables with the correct `auto_increment` value:

```
CALL addBrand();
```